# Angular2 creating and using Services

Tags: angular

I'm trying out Angular2 for the first time and am having some problems creating a service.  Actually in using that services.  I have created the following data service

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {recentActivity} from './app/components/recentActivity/model'

@Injectable()
export class RecentActivityDataService {

    loadList() {
        const items: Array<recentActivity> = [];
        items.push({
            url: 'From Service',
            name: 'From Service'
        });

        return items;
    }

}
```

Then in a component I have the following:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {recentActivity} from './model';
import {RecentActivityDataService} from './dataService';

@Component({
    selector: 'recentActivity',
    templateUrl: './app/components/recentActivity/recentActivity.html',
    providers: [RecentActivityDataService]
})
export class RecentActivity implements OnInit {

    items: Array<recentActivity> = [];

    constructor(private dataService: RecentActivityDataService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.items = this.dataService.loadList();
    }

}
```

When I pull up this component I'm getting the following error message

> "Uncaught (in promise): Cannot resolve all parameters for
>   'RecentActivity'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated
>   with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'RecentActivity'
>   is decorated with Injectable."

I don't know what I'm missing here since my service has the @Injectable on it and in my component I have it listed as a provider.  But in the constructor it is still failing saying it cannot resolve this.

In app.Component I have the following

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {StandardNavigation} from './navigation/standard';
import {RecentActivity} from './components/recentActivity/recentActivity';

@Component({
    selector: 'cranalytics',
    templateUrl: './app/main.html',
    directives: [StandardNavigation, RecentActivity]
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

I have tried the following changes.  In my Main I'm bootstrapping AppComponent:
bootstrap(AppComponent);

In AppComponent I have put the service as a provider there

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {StandardNavigation} from './navigation/standard';
import {RecentActivity} from './components/recentActivity/recentActivity';
import {RecentActivityDataService} from './components/recentActivity/dataService';

@Component({
    selector: 'cranalytics',
    templateUrl: './app/main.html',
    directives: [StandardNavigation, RecentActivity],
    providers: [RecentActivityDataService]
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

In Recent Activity I have imported the Data Service

```
import {Component, OnInit, Inject, forwardRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {recentActivity} from './model';
import {RecentActivityDataService} from './dataService';

@Component({
    selector: 'recentActivity',
    templateUrl: './app/components/recentActivity/recentActivity.html',
})
export class RecentActivity implements OnInit {

    items: Array<recentActivity> = [];

    constructor(  private dataService: RecentActivityDataService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.items = this.dataService.loadList();
    }

}
```

But that gives me the same error message

Comment: There is no class requesting `RecentActivity`. The error comes from somewhere else. Where do you have a constructor parameter of type `RecentActivity`?

Comment: What happens if you bootstrap the service instead of providing it on the component?

Comment: In App.Component I added the import line and the providers line and removed them from the RecentActivity component and I get the same error.

Comment: The only way that I can get it to work is if (using the original implementation listed in the question) is if I add
@Inject(forwardRef(() => RecentActivityDataService))
 before the parameter in the constructor, but I shouldn't have to do this based on what I have read

Comment: or reorder your classes in your source file or move each class to its own file

Comment: I can't get any DI to work.  I put in the forwardref thing just to try and continue forward.  So then in the dataservice class I tried import http and putting that in the constructor (while also adding it to the providers in the app.component.  When I do this I get the same error, but this time in the data service class, so basically none of the DI is working.  I must be missing something pretty basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to put recentActivity dependency in the bootstrap() so all the services can access it without import everywhere.

Comment: Even if they are listed in `bootstrap()` you still need to import the classes if you use the types. Importing and providing are mostly unrelated concepts. The former is to register the type in DI, the later is to make types you use in your code known to static code checker (linter) and to use them as keys for DI which still requires them to be imported.